# Add a javascript validation to each dropdown control in a grid in RowDatabound event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a template field in a GridView. The template field is a dropdown list that is generated dynamically in the RowDataBound event.

How can I add a Javascript validation to each of those dropdown lists when they're created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Dim gvItem As GridViewRow = e.Row
    If gvItem.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim DropDownList1 As DropDownList = gvItem.FindControl("DropDownList1")
        DropDownList1.Attributes("onchange") = "yourJavascriptValidationFunction(this);"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DropDownList.Attributes.Add("onChange", "yourjavascriptfunction");